# How to create a table of tables with different table lengths?

Tags: list-manipulation

Apologies for the basic question, but I can't figure it out. I'm very,very new to Mathematica and programming.

So I have two waves of data, first wave has 15 countries and 9 variables, wave 2 has 20 countries and also 9 variables. 
I defined tables for all the variables and defined the model-output as position of that table like so: `netwealth1[[1]]` etc. This works and the tables carry all the observations.

What I want to do visualise a table of variables by country of both waves of data together. I tried this:

defined a list of variables for both waves:

```
listofvariables = {paretostart1, paretostart2, alphawave1, alphawave2, 
   netwealthtotal1, netwealthtotal2, corrnetwealthtotal1, corrnetwealthtotal2, 
   oversamplingrate1, oversamplingrate2, percsharestop11, percsharestop12, 
   corrpercsharestop11, corrpercsharestop12, avwealth1, avwealth2, corravwealth1, 
   corravwealth2};
```

define labels:

```
labelsvariablen = {"Paretostart Wave I", "Paretostart Wave II", 
   "Pareto-Alpha Wave I", "Pareto-Alpha Wave II", "Total Net Wealth Wave I", 
   "Total Net Wealth Wave II", "Corrected Net Wealth Wave I", 
   "Corrected Net Wealth Wave II", "Oversamplingrate Wave I", 
   "Oversamplingrate Wave II", "Wealth-share Top Percentile Wave I", 
   "Wealth-share Top Percentile Wave II", 
   "Corrected Wealth-share Top Percentile WaveI", 
   "Corrected Wealth-share Top Percentile Wave II", "Average Wealth Wave I", 
   "Average Wealth Wave II", "Corrected Average Wealth Wave I", 
   "Corrected Average Wealth Wave II"};

labelscountries = {"Austria", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Germany", "Spain", "Finnland", 
   "France", "Greece", "Italy", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Portugal", 
   "Slovenia", "Slovakia", "Estonia", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Latvia", "Poland"};
```

then used transpose and prepend:

```
finaldata=Transpose[Prepend[listofvariables,labelsvariablen]]
```

and theoretically:

```
Prepend[finaldata,labelscountries]//Gridform
```

However, transposing does not work and I really do not know where I am going wrong, or how I could produce a table of table with labels differently.

Thank you very much, apologies for the ignorant question.

Comment: I formatted your code, then read this question twice.  I'm still not sure what you want.  `Transpose[{listofvariables, labelsvariablen}]` might be a start as those two lists are the same length and can be transposed, but how is this supposed to relate to the list of country names?  What is the *actual output* that you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt to answer the question. As Ms.Wizard said in a comment it is not clear what is desired outcome.

Data generation:

```
countryNames = CountryData["Countries", "Name"];
countryVariables = CountryData["Properties"];
commonVariables = {#, CountryData["USA", #]} & /@ 
   RandomSample[countryVariables, 30];
commonVariables = Cases[commonVariables, {_, _Quantity}][[All, 1]]
wave1Countries = RandomSample[countryNames, 4];
wave1Data = 
  Transpose@
   Outer[{#1, CountryData[##]} &, wave1Countries, commonVariables];
wave2Countries = RandomSample[countryNames, 5];
wave2Data = 
  Transpose@
   Outer[{#1, CountryData[##]} &, wave2Countries, commonVariables];
```

Make a table of tables (grid of grids, actually):

```
Grid[Partition[#, 2] &@
  MapThread[
   Grid[{{Style[#1, Blue, Bold], SpanFromLeft}, 
         {Grid[#2, Alignment -> Left], Grid[#3, Alignment -> Left]}}, 
        Alignment -> Top, Dividers -> All] &, 
   {commonVariables, wave1Data, wave2Data}], 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]